# Show/Hide a full screen overlay

Tags: jquery, css

I've set up a Fiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/nNUkr/

The full screen overlay appears but it doesn't disappear as i want it to (when clicked).

```
<div id="fullscreen" class="fullscreen_hide"></div>

<div id="button" class="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2000;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

.fullscreen_hide{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    opacity:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background:#141414;
}
.fullscreen_show{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3000;
    opacity:1;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background:#141414;
}
```

Code

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fullscreen_show');
});
$('.fullscreen_show').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('fullscreen_show');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNUkr/1/)

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fullscreen_show');
});

// use .on() to account for .fullscreen_show elements created later
$(document).on('click', '.fullscreen_show', function(){

    // removed .siblings() to include just the clicked div and not its siblings alone
    $(this).removeClass('fullscreen_show');
});
```

There were 2 problems with your code:

1. `$(this).siblings().removeClass('fullscreen_show');` - `$(this).siblings()` does not include the clicked div itself. It will remove the class `fullscreen_show` **only** from the clicked div's siblings.
2. At the point of binding, there are no elements with the class `fullscreen_show`. To counter this, you can use `.on()` on a higher level element to include dynamically created elements with the class `fullscreen_show`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Helpful to get some insight onto the code as well.